# How to recover rotation angle?

Tags: mesh, vertices, transforms

I have a rotated mesh and original mesh knowing the correspondence of vertices.Then how can I recover the rotation angles ?

Comment: are you trying to realign the local orientation with the orientation of a face of your mesh?

Comment: @moonboots -- yes, I believe Michael's comment on my earliest answer (Sept 22) indicates that is what he's looking for.  Perhaps there's and easier solution to my latest answer of Sept 26?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit terse, but if I'm interpreting correctly, you can select the mesh with the rotation you want and then the object you want to transform (recover), and use the Object menu -> Transform -> Apply Selected to Active.

[image]

However this will apply EVERY transformation, including Rotation and Scale.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work..I think I might restate my problem another way.Assume I have a mesh 1 with no transform.Then I duplicate it to mesh 2,give it some rotation and apply rotation transform.But I don't know the rotation value I set,how can I get the rotation value ?

Answer (score 0):

The following might work (see "cleanup" below), by choosing a face in the object with applied rotation, that you want to apply to an object with no rotaion.  Here, I have applied the rotation of a Cube:

[image]

I then put the Object with Rotation applied in Edit Mode, and in View: "Align the View to Active" : "Top" (notice that the un-rotated Cube on the left now APPEARS rotated relative to the View angle that is normal to the cube on the right.

[image]

I not select the un-rotated left Cube and Use Object : Transform : Align to Transform Orientation, and in the popup panel I select "View".

CLEANUP: When I check the rotations, I had applied a 30.2 deg Y axis rotation to the object with applied rotation and now I have an object with a 30.2 deg X axis rotation and 90 deg and Z=90 that need cleanup.

[image]

This may also be an over-simplifed example using a cube, but you may be able to use a cube of perhaps better to use an Empty as an intermediary object.

Comment: hopefully other experts like @moonboots might comments on an easier way, or how to correctly align the view for the correct angle (front instead of top?).

Comment: It seems that euler angle can be determined by correspending points by solving some linear equations..So maybe a script will do ?